# Enterprise Ethereum Alliance - Enterprise Ethereum Architecture Stack (EEAS)

Tags: architecture, enterprise

I read through the just released EEA Stack and Specification accessible at https://entethalliance.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/EEA-Architecture-Stack-Spring-2018.pdf

It is a great first step in the right direction in the delineation of responsibilities in achieving separation of concerns -- Network, Core Blockchain, Application.

However, it is only one page. Thought if someone could share if best practices, specifications, security (privacy) and scalability would be addressed in the same document in the future or this document is the final copy?

Enterprise Ethereum Alliance - Enterprise Ethereum Architecture Stack (EEAS)